# Graham scan when the points are already sorted by one of the coordinates

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull, grahams-scan

The Wikipedia entry for [convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) states:

> Graham scan — O(n log n)
> A slightly more sophisticated, but much more efficient algorithm, published by Ronald Graham in 1972. If the points are already sorted by one of the coordinates or by the angle to a fixed vector, then the algorithm takes O(n) time.

However, I couldn't find any references taking as input a list of points sorted by one of the coordinates. In that case, is there a preliminary step that needs to be done to get them sorted by the angle? Trying a few examples, I don't think I can just use the points sorted by, let's say, the x-axis value in the same way I use them sorted by the angle.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain

Comment: Thank you, so it's indeed a variant of the Graham Scan. Now to figure out why it works :)